# ActionLink adds controller argument to link when trying to hide the controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want want to make the controller depending on the value of a group, so I have the following route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
     name: "Default",
     url: "{group}/{action}",
     defaults: new { group = "Default", action = "Index" }
).RouteHandler = new MyRouteHandler();
```

With the following routehandler and httphandler:

```
public class MyRouteHandler : IRouteHandler
{
    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        return new MyHttpHandler(requestContext);
    }
}

public class MyHttpHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    RequestContext _requestContext;

    public MyHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        _requestContext = requestContext;
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var groupName = _requestContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("group");

        // Select the controller, e.g. Home:

        _requestContext.RouteData.Values.Add("controller", "Home");

        IControllerFactory factory = ControllerBuilder.Current.GetControllerFactory();
        IController controller = factory.CreateController(_requestContext, "Home");
        if (controller != null)
        {
            controller.Execute(_requestContext);
        }
    }
}
```

This all working but if a put a @Html.ActionLink("Index", "Index") on the page it results in the following link:

[a href="/?controller=Home"]Index[/a]

Can somebody tell me why the controller argument is added when using the Html.ActionLink? (I don't want to add the controller=Home argument added to the link.)

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Default",
   url: "{group}/{action}/{controller}",
   defaults: new { group = "Default", action = "Index", controller = "Home" }
);

@Html.ActionLink("Index", "Index", new {group = "Group"});
```

Comment: This is not a solution for my problem. The controller is still in the url.

Comment: @Tim Are you remove your custom Routehandler. Example above gives me following link: http://.../Group, if current controller is "HomeController"